# C# Nullable<T> query comprehension - "expression is always true" warning

Tags: c#, linq, resharper, monads

I amused myself by writing Select and SelectMany implementations for the `Nullable<T>` type in C# (enabling the LINQ query comprehension syntax. When I write some test queries the compiler gives me a warning though:

```
public static void Test()
{
    var z1 =
        from x in 5.Nullable()
        from y in 6.Nullable()
        select x + y;

    var z2 =
        from x in 3.Nullable()
        from y in default(DateTime?)
        select y.Month == x;

    var result =
        from x in z1
        from y in z2
        select x == 11 && !y;

    Console.WriteLine(result.HasValue // <-- this expression is "always true"
        ? result.Value.ToString()
        : "computation failed");
}
```

How can it claim this? I know it isn't interpreting the queries above, because if I change the code so HasValue SHOULD be false (e.g. changing x in z1 to 20), it still gives the warning. Is this a bug in the compiler or have I made a mistake?

I believe my method implementations are correct, but here they are for reference:

```
public static T? Nullable<T>(this T x)
    where T : struct 
{
    return x;
}

public static U? Select<T, U>(this T? n, Func<T, U> f)
    where T : struct
    where U : struct
{
    return n.HasValue
        ? f(n.Value)
        : default(U?);
}

public static U? SelectMany<T, U>(this T? n, Func<T, U?> f)
    where T : struct
    where U : struct
{
    return n.HasValue
        ? f(n.Value)
        : default(U?);
}

public static V? SelectMany<T, U, V>(this T? n, Func<T, U?> f, Func<T, U, V> g)
    where T : struct
    where U : struct
    where V : struct
{
    if (!n.HasValue) return default(V?);

    var u = f(n.Value);
    return u.HasValue
        ? g(n.Value, u.Value)
        : default(V?);
}
```

Comment: What do you think the result of `select x == 11 && !y` is? And why do you think it could ever not have a value?

Comment: @mason - The warning is claimed to be on the `result.HasValue` line, and `result` has type `bool?`.

Comment: @JonSkeet - Yes, you are right thanks.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this - which version of Visual Studio are you using? Do you have any plugins such as Resharper? If so, try disabling them.

Comment: This is a situation where using `var` is inappropriate - if it's not clear what the type of your variable is, you should explicitly define your variable instead of using the implicit `var`.

Comment: @mason `result` is of type `bool?` and it will be true if the expression is true, false if it's false, and null if either of the previous computations contained or resulted in a null.

Comment: It's a resharper warning. You can disable it just for this case. Btw, thanks for this question, didn't know that you can build your own implementations of `SelectMany` which work in LINQ's query syntax.

Comment: @JonSkeet I'm using VS2015 community edition with R#, and indeed, the warning went away when I disabled R#

Comment: @TimSchmelter: You can do all kinds of weird things with query expressions... like selecting from a type name. See https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2008/02/29/odd-query-expressions/ for a couple of examples.

Comment: @RenéVogt take another look at my linq method implementations, z1 and z2 can be null

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ReSharper warning is demonstrably inaccurate. Consider this variation of your code:

```
var z1 =
    from x in default(int?)
    from y in 6.Nullable()
    select x + y;

if (z1.HasValue)
{
}
```

ReSharper will mark the condition as "always true":

[image]

But in the debugger we can clearly see that it's false:

[image]

So I would say that it's a bug in ReSharper.

---

(For future reference, [it has been submitted by the OP to the issue tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-458849).)